# Term for "a pattern that repeats once induced"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example, let's say that I went to sleep one night at 5:00 am. Out of exhaustion, I would most likely sleep until the late afternoon. Since I woke up so late, I wouldn't be tired until very early in the morning, maybe 5:00 am again. This pattern would repeat over and be hard to break out of. My question is, what would we call this type of pattern? Another example would be smoking; you begin to smoke and it's very hard to stop. I'm not looking for "addiction", because that implies that I am physically and mentally dependent on the object.

Comment: Did you think of *habit*?

Comment: @Robusto - I did, but what I'm describing isn't really a habit. What I'm describing involuntarily repeats, regardless of the wish of the person it affects, and it doesn't necessarily benefit said person. For example, in the above situation, I don't want to go to sleep really late, but I have to because I did it the previous night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apt term for this is *vicious circle* or *vicious cycle*. According to [NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vicious+circle?q=vicious%20circle), the definition goes thus:

> a sequence of reciprocal cause and effect in which two or more elements intensify and aggravate each other, leading inexorably to a worsening of the situation.

In your own words: *This pattern would repeat over [and over] and be hard to break out of.* I cannot think of a better phrase than *vicious cycle*.

Comment: Good ones are sometimes called virtuous cycles or virtuous circles.

Comment: Hah @Merk!! I just stopped short of including that in my answer! Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You might use **self-sustaining** or **feedback loop**.

Comment: Your answer would be expected to cite the sources and some justification for these terms.